ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread' after working previously with no changes to the environment
I created a script last night to connect to my google sheets. It worked properly on my PC, and I pushed my changes to GitHub. I then worked on it some more on my personal laptop, pushed my changes to GitHub and then called it a day. I came back to my PC this morning to work on it some more. I pulled my changes and opened the notebook, and the script no longer works. I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import gspread
      2 from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
      4 scopes = {
      5     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
      6     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
      7 }

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'

Did I do something in my workflow to mess this up? The package was installed using pip
pip install gspread. I also tried !pip install gspread AND  !pip3 install gspread within the notebook and it returns the following:
Requirement already satisfied: gspread in c:\users\nate\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (6.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth>=1.12.0 in c:\users\nate\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gspread) (2.32.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1 in c:\users\nate\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gspread) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\nate\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth>=1.12.0->gspread) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\nate\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth>=1.12.0->gspread) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in c:\users\nate\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth>=1.12.0->gspread) (4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\users\nate\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1->gspread) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.7.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\nate\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth>=1.12.0->gspread) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\nate\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1->gspread) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0.0 in c:\users\nate\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1->gspread) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\nate\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1->gspread) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\nate\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1->gspread) (3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\nate\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1->gspread) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\nate\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1->gspread) (2024.2.2)

What am I missing to get the script to work?
I need help in understanding why the module is not working although it is installed in the correct environment. I even tried reinstalling the package but I have had no luck.

I'm also having problems now just trying to import gspread after installing it several times. It's just throwing a bunch of errors right from the import line

Probably something to do with the python version. I got it working by downgrading the gspread version to 5.12.4v
pip install --force-reinstall -v "gspread==5.12.4"
